# Backward compatibility issues with json libraries in rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

to_json method in rails 2.0.2 for objects(say user model object with id and name)used to give simple output in the form

```
{"id":"xyz","name":"hello"}
```

But while upgrading the rails to 2.3.4 it gives the output as

```
{"user":{"id":"xyz","name":"hello"}}
```

This is breaking my most of the frontend code.

Is there way to get the results in the same fashion as in 2.0.2 ???

Looking for a speedy answer from you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file `config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb` and change `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true` to false. That should do it. See the [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) documentation.

If for some reason you don't have that file, this is what it should look like in a default Rails 2.3.x app.

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# These settings change the behavior of Rails 2 apps and will be defaults
# for Rails 3. You can remove this initializer when Rails 3 is released.

if defined?(ActiveRecord)
  # Include Active Record class name as root for JSON serialized output.
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true

  # Store the full class name (including module namespace) in STI type column.
  ActiveRecord::Base.store_full_sti_class = true
end

# Use ISO 8601 format for JSON serialized times and dates.
ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format = true

# Don't escape HTML entities in JSON, leave that for the #json_escape helper.
# if you're including raw json in an HTML page.
ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = false
```